# Forma de Otimizar a expressão Regular de Substring no BD Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
SELECT us.FULL_NAME, us.USER_ID FROM knta_users us WHERE USER_ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PRJ.PRJ_PROJECT_MANAGER_USER_ID, '[^#@#]+', 1, LEVEL) AS GP_ID 
FROM KCRT_FG_PFM_PROJECT PRJ WHERE PRJ.PRJ_PROJECT_ID = '30580' CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (PRJ.PRJ_PROJECT_MANAGER_USER_ID,'[^#@#]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

Ela funciona, mas demora muito para carregar.

Será que existe uma forma alternativa de fazer essa consulta? Pois o sistema que a consome não carrega os dados por tempo excedido.

Esse trecho vai buscar no banco um campo que armazena vários usuários separados por caracteres especiais (ex: `usuario1#@#usuario2`) e trazer cada um deles em uma linha.

Comment: Primeira sugestão , normalize a tabela , sqls complicados pois as tabelas não estão normalizadas, não sendo possível tente um subselect com EXISTS e LIKE.

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas o que você quer dizer com normalizar a tabela?

Comment: No lugar de ter uma "string" com os usuários concatenados ter uma segunda tabela e cada usuário numa coluna , procure por FORMAS NORMAIS. A sql seria trivial.

Comment: É que na verdade a estrutura da tabela já está montada dessa forma. A única forma seria alterar a forma de como é gravada a informação? Só para você entender esse campo armazena quem é o gerente de cada projeto, mas podem ser várias pessoas, por isso ele vai concatenando, mas para exibir eu preciso separar esses usuários.

Comment: Tenta por subselect e exists

Answer (score 0):

[Nao tenho pontuação ainda para comentar] - Você ja tentou executar um plano de execução para verificar se esta ocorrendo algum fullscan? Se sim, tenta procurar um index para utilizar e realizar paralelismo para a query ficar mais performática.

Comment: Você pode atualizar as estatísticas do banco para melhorar a performance, obtive bons resultados realizando essa prática, alinhando ao estudo do plano de execução conforme o colega acima mencionou, você pode melhorar seu select utilizando colunas indices que ja tem uma consulta otimizada na tabela. 

EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME=>'OWNER', TABNAME=>'NOME_TABELA', cascade=>true);